# In xcode 4, what's the difference between "other c flags" and "other c++ flags"?

Tags: c++, c, xcode4, compiler-flags

Also, does listing them directly across from the respective label set them for both debug and release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xcode help provides fairly clear definitions:

> **Name:** Other C Flags
>
> **Abstract:** Space-separated list of additional flags to pass to the compiler for C and Objective-C files. Be sure to backslash-escape any arguments that contain spaces or special characters (e.g. path names that may contain spaces). Use this setting if Xcode does not already provide UI for a particular C or Objective-C compiler flag. [OTHER_CFLAGS]
>
> **Name:** Other C++ Flags
>
> **Abstract:** Space-separated list of additional flags to pass to the compiler for C++ and Objective-C++ files. Be sure to backslash-escape any arguments that contain spaces or special characters (e.g. path names that may contain spaces). Use this setting if Xcode does not already provide UI for a C++ or Objective-C++ compiler flag. [OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS]

So "Other C Flags" are passed to the compiler when compiling C and Obj-C source files.  "Other C++ Flags" are passed to the compiler when compiling C++ and Obj-C++ source files.

To your second question: Yes.  You can specify flags for debug or release or another configuration by hitting the disclosure triangle to the left of "Other C Flags" and then putting the desired flag on the line corresponding to the desired configuration.

Answer (score 1):

C flags are used when compiling C and Objective-C source files.  C++ flags are used when compiling C++ and Objective-C++ source files.  They're analogous to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in `make`.

I'm afraid I don't know about debug vs. release builds, but I'd presume they'd be used in both cases.  Certainly you can easily try it out.